# sorting algorithm met in interview：sorting in a double linked list

Tags: sorting, doubly-linked-list, heapsort

To sort a double linked list with a space complexity of O(1) and an average time complexity of O(nlgn). The worst O(n^2) time should be avoided. How can you meet this requires?

My interviewer hinted that it should be a improved version of heap sort.

Comment: Isn't it pretty much standard heapsort as described by Fouler?

Comment: Without any improvement? Standard heapsort on a array can have O(nlgn) time. But wouldn't finding the subtree of a node in a double linked list be time costly?

Comment: When asked about time complexity of O(n lgn), what operation you were talking about? Because in all sorts (heapsort, quicksort) with those O(some function of `n`) they are talking about comparisons/moves, not about data access operations